# Changing color of only one gameobject

Tags: unity, c#

So i have this script the checks if my mouse cursor is over the block and if it is i want the block to change color

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BasicBlockFunction : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject Block;
public Color StartingColor;
public Color HighlightColor;
Color color;
Ray ray;
RaycastHit hit;



// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    MouseOver();
}

void MouseOver()
{
    ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
    {
        print(hit.collider.name);
        Block.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = HighlightColor;
    }
    else
    {
        Block.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = StartingColor;
    }

 }


}
```

I want to change the color only for the gameobject i have my mouse on.

Comment: it work but changes the color on every gameobjects with this script.

Comment: i want it to change only the color of the block i have my mouse cursor on.

Comment: You could do it based off of an `if(hit.gameObject.tag == "object") {
    // Do stuff.
}`

Comment: hit.gameobject doesn't work because it isn't a raycaster.

Comment: Here seems to be some confusion here. What is this script attached to? It should be the camera not the block. And any object with a collider can be hit by a raycast

Comment: ^ It will only not work if you do not have a collider attached.

Comment: i have a collider attached

Comment: What do you mean it won't work with a collider attached? Of course it will.

Comment: Whatever object this scrip is attached to will cast a ray. It doesn't determine behaviour when hit by an array

Comment: I am confused! Where do i attach the script? I attached it to the game object.

Comment: This casts an array from the camera so have it on the camera.

Comment: Ok i got that working but i want to have multiple blocks and whichever block i touch i changes the color for the block that i have on my script.

Comment: I dont want that to happen.

Comment: Yes so at the moment you are referencing your Block type but you want to refer to the hit variable in the raycast. This will be the block you are pointing at

Answer (score 3):

If your block objects each have their own colliders, you can do this with a script you attach to each block, leveraging Unity's built-in [OnMouseEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseEnter.html) / [OnMouseExit](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseExit.html) events:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Renderer))]
public class HoverHighlight : MonoBehaviour {

    public Material highlightMaterial;

    Renderer _renderer;
    Material _originalMaterial;

    void Start() {
       _renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
       _originalMaterial = _renderer.sharedMaterial;
    }

    void OnMouseEnter() {
       _renderer.sharedMaterial = highlightMaterial;
    }

    void OnMouseExit() {
       _renderer.sharedMaterial = _originalMaterial;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the material color, you could change the material.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BasicBlockFunction : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject Block;
public Material StartingMaterial;
public Material HighlightMaterial;
Color color;
Ray ray;
RaycastHit hit;



// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    MouseOver();
}

void MouseOver()
{
    ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
    {
        print(hit.collider.name);
        Block.GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial = HighlightMaterial;
    }
    else
    {
        Block.GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial = StartingMaterial;
    }

 }


}
```

This would give you more control over the highlight material.

Comment: doesn't work :(

Comment: @HearPcGaming whenever you're giving feedback on an answer, or trying to describe a problem, please ensure you always give more details than "doesn't work." You should describe the exact symptoms you're seeing (eg. error messages, unexpected behaviour, absence of desired behaviour) - this gives other users better guidance about how to help you and improve their answers. Here I infer that, because this script doesn't change how it's selecting which block to change, it has the same issue as your original version: multiple copies of the script all run, changing multiple blocks instead of just one

Comment: It has the same issue as my original version.

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to a Block game object not the object being hit by the array. To change the object the raycast hits use the hit variable. This stores all info about the object including its material and colour.